# VB script works on Windows XP but not in Windows 7

Tags: windows, vbscript

I have a simple VBScript that I use in my webpage to rotate images located in a folder named "media\rotate".  My script works fine when I run it in Windows XP but it does not work if I run it from Windows 7.  I am using Windows 7 32Bit, while my Windows XP is a Service Pack 3.

My script looks like this:

```
 Dim gRotatorFiles, gFileCount, gFileIndex

  gFileCount = 0
  gFileIndex = 1

  Sub LoadRotatorImages()
    Dim oFileSystem, oFolder, oFile

    Set gRotatorFiles = CreateObject("POSCommonObjects.POSCollection")
    Set oFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If oFileSystem.FolderExists("C:\Program Files\Customer Display\media\rotate") Then
      Set oFolder = oFileSystem.GetFolder("C:\Program Files\Customer Display\media\rotate")

      If Not oFolder Is Nothing Then
        If Not oFolder.Files Is Nothing Then
          For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
            gRotatorFiles.Add oFile.Path, oFile.Name
          Next
        End If
      End If
    End If

    gFileCount = gRotatorFiles.Count
    Set oFileSystem = Nothing
    Set oFolder = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing
  End Sub

  Sub RotateImages()
    If gFileCount > 0 Then
      gFileIndex = gFileIndex + 1

      If gFileIndex >= gFileCount Then
        gFileIndex = 1
      End If

      LoadCurrentImage()
      window.setTimeout "RotateImages()", 10000
    End If
  End Sub

  Sub LoadCurrentImage()
    document.all("AdImage").Filters(0).Apply
    document.all("AdImage").src = gRotatorFiles(CInt(gFileIndex))
    document.all("AdImage").Filters(0).Play
  End Sub
```

Then I call it in my page like this:

```
<script language="vbscript" src="RotateImages.vbs"></script>
<script language="vbscript">
Sub Window_OnLoad()
RotateImages()
End Sub
</script>
```

And in the body:

```
<img id="AdImage" style="FILTER: prodig:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.GradientWipe(duration=2)" src="">
```

I wonder if someone knows what the inconsistencies between those operating systems might cause these issues or if it is something in my code.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?  Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: Also, what is `POSCommonObjects.POSCollection`?  That's not something I've ever heard of, and Google doesn't have anything on it.

Comment: Those are just classes in my code behind that I am calling.  When I use this script with Windows XP it will display the images in my media/rotate folder dynamically.  However, when I run it in Windows 7 it does not display anything.

Comment: Seems to me like the answer lies within those classes.  Since they're basically a black box to me, I can't make a conjecture beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

To base the trouble shooting on something testable:

```
' On Error Resume Next

' global var used by LoadRotatorImages() and RotateImages()
Dim gRotatorFiles

' preparation: init gRotatorFiles
Sub LoadRotatorImages()
'   Set gRotatorFiles = CreateObject("POSCommonObjects.POSCollection")
    Set gRotatorFiles = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
'   Set gRotatorFiles = CreateObject("System.Collection.ArrayList")
    gRotatorFiles.Add "fi"
    gRotatorFiles.Add "fa"
    gRotatorFiles.Add "fo"
End Sub

' real work: using gRotatorFiles
Sub RotateImages()
    For Each f In gRotatorFiles
        WScript.Echo f
    Next
End Sub

' Then I call it in my page like this:
' but I forgot to call LoadRotatorImages()
LoadRotatorImages()
RotateImages()
```

output:

```
cscript 23547130.vbs
fi
fa
fo
```

**First shot:**

In the code you posted, you don't call LoadRotatorImages(). If adding this call does **not** fix your problem, disable the EVIL global OERN I suspect in your code and publish error messages.

**Second shot:**

"Not getting errors" is caused by an EVIL `On Error Resume Next` or (perhaps; I don't use IE) by some "Keep quiet about errors" setting(s) in the Internet Options. Evidence: If you activate the OERN and the bad CreateObject in the demo code, you get no output at all. After disabling The OERN again, you get a `can't create object: 'System.Collection.ArrayList'` message.

It's up to you whether you use OERN in your production code, but you shouldn't ask questions here without having tested your code without OERN (or equivalent IE settings).

If the code runs with neither error nor output even when "break on error" is on, try to add diagnostics for important pre-requisites. E.g.

```
' On Error Resume Next
...
    Set gRotatorFiles = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
'   Set gRotatorFiles = CreateObject("System.Collection.ArrayList")
    WScript.Echo "****", TypeName(gRotatorFiles)
...
```

results in:

```
cscript 23547130.vbs
**** ArrayList
```

If `TypeName(gRotatorFiles)` does not delivers something reasonable

- double check the installation of the component
- consider using a 'more native' collection (Scripting.Dictionary, ArrayList, ...)

Comment: Hi Ekkehard.  I called the LoadRotatorImages() but I did not get any error messages either.